# Spring Framework Saving Data to Multiple Tables

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, sql-insert

Newbie here...

I'm working on a Spring MVC app and their JDBC api for data access. How would I go about saving data to multiple tables? The insertion needs to be such that if there's an error or something goes wrong, nothing gets inserted and rolled-back. Would this be Spring's transaction support? If so, the official documentation for transaction support is very confusing to me. Does anyone have a good source for learning how to do that?

I'm using Spring 3.1, Oracle 11g, and Tomcat 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, spring supports transaction. You can use DataSourceTransactionManager to configure your bean.IF you find xml mapping confusing you can use annotation @Transactional. Spring's annotation support for transactions are really simple. **Spring in Action** book has examples for transaction management.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to give a try (the book that is).